# show tooltip when move on options in select (jquery or javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display a jquery tooltip:

- while moving over options(with up and down arrows in keyboard) in focused select option (without multiple atribute).
- while moving over options(with mouse pointer) in a open select option (without multiple atribute).

the idea it´s basically like the above example from jquery page(URL attached)

https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

but without multiple atribute, and display red text in a jquery tooltip.

This was my last attempt, but tooltip triggers when hover the select-option.

```
<select id="garden" title="">
    <option value="0">Select and Option</option>
    <option value="1">OPTION ONE</option>
    <option value="2">OPTION TWO</option>
</select>

$( "select" )
.change(function() {
var str = "";
$( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
    if ($( this ).val() != 0) {
        if ($( this ).val() == 1) {
            str += " tooltip one";
        } else if ($( this ).val() == 2) {
            str += " tooltip two";
        }
        $('#garden').prop('title', str);
        $("#garden").tooltip();
    }
});
}).trigger( "change" );
```

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: thanks for you´re reply, code added...

Answer (score 0):

Try hovering over the options. The change event only fires once the user has selected an option.

```
$( "select option" ).hover(function() {
   // The rest of your code to show a tootlip.
});
```